# CSS Animation on Hover reverts without completion

Tags: css

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #517fa4, #243949);
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.card-container {
  perspective: 900px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 27px 55px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 17px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.front, .back {
  position: absolute;
  background: #7FC6A4;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}

.front {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.back {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">User</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="fa fa-cogs"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">Settings</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="fa fa-code"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">Code</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a simple CSS animation of a card flip. Could you please tell me why the animation on hover sometimes does not complete and reverts back? If you try hovering on the card, you may see that sometimes, the card flips partially and returns back even though the my mouse is still hovering over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
.card:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

to this:

```
.card-container:hover .card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

**Edit:**

Add an additional container for the card and add a margin-right to it as shown below.

```
<div class="card-container">
     <div class="card-flipper">
          <div class="card">
               ...
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card-flipper{
     margin-right:20px;
}
```

Comment: Close!  Might I suggest amending your answer to be `.card-container:hover .card` instead for the selector?  Also, yes, there should be a wrapper for card that has the margin on it instead of directly attaching margin to the `.card`.

Comment: @JosephMarikle you are right. please write this in an answer so that i can mark that as the correct solution

Comment: @takeradi  Phani has the right solution.  It just needs amended slightly.  I'll write a separate answer if this one isn't edited here over the next few minutes.  In the meantime, here is a fiddle demonstrating the wrapper and this solution: https://jsfiddle.net/3km3jnLb/

Comment: @JosephMarikle: Thanks for the correction there, I updated my answer.

Comment: @Phani, please do not forget the margin part that JosephMarikle mentioned. Need that too to fix it completely.